# precision of adc LSB

Tags: precision, adc

I am using a 24 bit ADC and trying to calculate the minimum voltage readable.
The ADC is signed 24b bit so there is only 23 effective bits.  The ADC full scale reading is 5v so I calculate the LSB as follows.

> double LSBval24 = 5.0/(pow(2,23)-1);

Now for the interesting part.  That calculation yields slightly different results on a Raspberry pi running Debian 32bit OS compared to the calculator on Windows 10 64bit.

The Pi output is obtained vi the following code

> char LSB[150];
>
> snprintf(LSB, 150, "LSB = %.38f", LSBval24 );

That means the LSBval24 calculation itself could be causing the difference or the *snprintf* conversion could be causing the problem or the Win 10 calculator is wrong.

Showing 38 decimal places...

```
Pi  = 0.00000059604651880818829633949113011582
Win = 0.00000059604651880818829634050087219487
```

So I guess my question is, given the limit of 23 bits of precision of the ADC
(1) which answer is more correct?
(2) how many digits (not bits) of precision is the limit of accuracy for this ADC.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found that the answer to question 2 is 6.9 digits based on ln(2)/ln(10) * 23 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You are discussing differences beginning at the 19 digit (decimal).
Most voltage references have tolerances in the range of +-0.1% if they are well trimmed. So the reference tolerance will become visible at about 0.59nV.

Looking to the nV: A 1K resistor has a noise of 4nV/SQRT(Hz) at room temperature. What happens below some nV is noise anyway (unless you can cool the design to close to 0K during operation)

The 23bit simply mean you can detect a change of the signal if it exceeds about 0.59uV. But it doesn't mean full scale is that accurat. This is rather limited by the reference voltage than by the ADC.